# Create new Images in a folder

Tags: python, saving-data

Im a beginner in python and trying to implement something for my master thesis.

Im trying to add a black border to my pictures, but my Issue is I want to add a border to all my pictures from my directory `/dataset/OldImages/0/*` and generate the new pictures with my black border to the directory `/dataset/NewImages/0/`.

This is my code what I did:

```
images = glob.glob('dataset/oldImages/0/*')
for i in images:
    img = Image.open(images)
    img_with_border = ImageOps.expand(img, border=70, fill='black')
    new_path('dataset/newImages/0')
    img_with_border.save(new path, 'png')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mhmdysfrmzngl/PycharmProjects/Sign2Math2/imagePadding.py", line 21, in <module>
    img = Image.open(images)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2615, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `Image.open(i)` instead of passing in the entire list called `images`?

Comment: Yeah that right!!